# Adding bloom effect to an image using CV2

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently working on a simple photo editor using CV2 in the backend and I'm wondering whether it is possible to add a [bloom effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_(shader_effect)) to the image using CV2.

Thanks for every help!

Comment: cv2 gives you image as `numpy.array` and it gives access to every pixel - so you can do whatever you like - but you will have to write all code on your own. But it means you have to know algorithm for `bloom effect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can achieve a bloom effect in Python/OpenCV as follows:

```
 - Read the input
 - Convert to HSV colorspace as floats and separate channels
 - Invert the saturation channel and multiply with the value channel, since to find white, we need low saturation and high brightness
 - Blur the product and convert to 3 channels
 - Blend the blurred image with the original applying gain to the blurred image
 - Save the result
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('barn.jpg')

# set arguments
thresh_value = 245  # threshold to find white
blur_value = 50     # bloom smoothness
gain = 6            # bloom gain in intensity

# convert image to hsv colorspace as floats
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV).astype(np.float64)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)

# Desire low saturation and high brightness for white
# So invert saturation and multiply with brightness
sv = ((255-s) * v / 255).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(sv, thresh_value, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# blur and make 3 channels
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (0,0), sigmaX=blur_value, sigmaY=blur_value)
blur = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# blend blur and image using gain on blur
result = cv2.addWeighted(img, 1, blur, gain, 0)

# save output image
cv2.imwrite('barn_bloom.jpg', result)

# display IN and OUT images
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('sv', sv)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clean and helpful answer  that helps a lot!

Comment: Alternately, you can simply threshold on white using cv2.inRange() rather than the S,V approach.